# Aggregator items update

Tags: feeds

I've implemented a RSS feed with aggregator on my website. 
It works well but i'd like to know if it is possible to force Aggregator to update the items with a function. 
I need to use it in a custom module but i don't find anything in the Aggregator API.

Thank you !

Edit : problem solved (aggregator_refresh function)